# Replacing a column's value with 1 if it's over 100

Tags: awk, sed

There is a way to put '1' when find a number greater than 100 in a specific column?

For example in a file I have this.

```
695, 610976, 488567
```

The third column (`488567`) is more than 100, so I would like this:

```
695, 610976, 1
```

Comment: What have you tried? regex can't "do" anything except match. It requires a language/tool to replace matched input with something else, so command have you tried and what happened?

Comment: Not sure of your notation. What is `1-100`?

Comment: @jas I'm sure he means `100`

Comment: Yes, greater than 100.

Comment: Removing the regex tag since this is a math problem, not a string matching problem.

Answer (score 1):

With awk:

```
 awk '{print $1,$2,($3>100)? 1 : $3}' infile.txt > outfile.txt
```

You could also totally math this out using boolean logic, without the Ternary operator:

```
  awk '{print $1,$2, ($3<=100)*$3+($3>100)*1}' infile.txt > outfile.txt
```

Comment: Thanks for support. How could a condition be made, that if it is greater than 100 that puts 1, and if not that leave the value that this?.

Comment: That's what the condition is here `($3>100) ? 1 : $3` That says "If the third column is greater than 100 `($3>100)`, then 1 `? 1`,  else whatever value is in the third column `: $3`". The `(<test>) ? <result if true> : <result if false>` format is called a "Ternary" operatory. It's just a short hand, in-line `if` statement.

Comment: Thanks, but when I use this condition awk '{print $ 1, $ 2, ($ 3 <= 100) * $ 3 + ($ 3> 100) * 1} infile.txt> outfile.txt, replace the value greater than 100 in the third column, but if it is smaller it also replaces it

For example, I have my input.txt file with these values

459, 16579, 485225

Aca complies and replaces with 1. But I have another input.txt file

459, 16579, 3

And in the same way put the 1, leaving it like this.

459, 16579, 1

Comment: Curious. Go with the first example since the ternary operatory is a bit clearer than the boolean math. This may be due to versions of awk or something since the boolean version works on my machine.

Comment: I'm on Gnu Awk 4.0.1. `echo "10 12 50" | awk '{print $1,$2, ($3<=100)*$3+($3>100)*1}'` results in `10 12 50` as expected.

Comment: Thanks for the support, you helped me a lot. Be fine.

Answer (score -1):

This is a parameter-dependant solution, (g)**awk** oneliner, tested on gawk v5.0.0 (windows 10):

```
awk -v n=3 -v maxval=100 -v repval=1 '{$n = $n > maxval ? repval : $n; print}' test.txt
```

You can parametrize the column to check, the maxval and the replacement value. Also, works on files with any number of columns.

Be careful: field separator is comma by default, meaning that each field (except first) in the input starts with a whitespace. This might cause some issues on certain awk versions, if the whitespace is forcing the field to be a string and not a number. Awk should be robust, but be careful anyway.

Tested on input:

```
1, 2, 3
4, 5, 6
150, 280, 999
```

returns:

```
1, 2, 3
4, 5, 6
150, 280, 1
```

Further caveat:

A string input, like `pears, apples, bananas` will return `pears, apples, 1`